# Scala slick: how to overload === operator

Tags: scala, operator-overloading, slick

I need to overload === in the following query

```
users.filter(_.id === userId)
```

so that I can apply some mapping to "userId" before running the actual query.

Looking at the slick definition:

```
def === [P2, R](e: Rep[P2])(implicit om: o#arg[B1, P2]#to[Boolean, R]) =
  om.column(Library.==, n, e.toNode)
```

it is not clear how I can achieve this. There userId parameter is an externally visible hash which needs to be mapped to the database primary key value.